# selecting balls w.p. 1/2

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $n$ balls in the beginning. In each round, each ball is retained with probability $1/2$ and discarded with probability $1/2$. What is the probability that there is still a ball (or more) left after $r$ rounds? Just need an asymptotic answer.

The exact probability is

$$\sum_{1\leq s_r\leq s_{r-1}\leq \cdots \leq s_0 = n} \frac{1}{2^{s_0+\cdots+s_{r-1}}} \binom{s_0}{s_1}\binom{s_1}{s_2}\cdots \binom{s_{r-1}}{s_r}$$

but I am not sure how to find an asymptotic value. The product of the binomial coefficients is a multinomial coefficient but it looks still hard to deal with the power of 2 in the denominator.

Also I would suspect there is a phase transition depending on whether $r < \log n$ or $r > C\log n$. At the moment let's suppose that $r < \log n$.